# Python Mock Patch Two Functions that are similar

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Let's say I have a function that has two similar function calls:

```
def foo():
  test = one_func("SELECT * from Users;")
  test1 = one_func("SELECT * from Addresses;")
  return test, test1
```

How do I patch each of these function contents? Here's my attempt:

```
@patch('one_func')
def test_foo(self, mock_one_func):
     mock_one_func.return_value = one_func("SELECT * from TestUsers;")
     mock_one_func.return_value = one_func("SELECT * from TestAddresses;")
```

But I think this method patches `one_func` as a whole per function. Which results to:

```
def foo():
  test = one_func("SELECT * from TestUsers;")
  test1 = one_func("SELECT * from TestUsers;")
  return test, test1
```

Then on the next line

```
def foo():
  test = one_func("SELECT * from TestAddresses;")
  test1 = one_func("SELECT * from TestAddresses;")
  return test, test1
```

What I want to happen in the patched function is.

```
def foo():
  test = one_func("SELECT * from TestUsers;")
  test1 = one_func("SELECT * from TestAddresses;")
  return test, test1
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve what you need is using `side_effect` instead of `return_value`. `side_effect` can be many things. If it is an `Exception` class or object, it will raise that exception whenever the patched method is called. If it is a list of values, will return each value in sequence for each method call. If it is a function, will execute that function with the parameters from each mocked method call.

Here is a working example, where I show you how to use a list of values on `side_effect` and a `side_effect` function. What's nice about using a function is that you can make it return specific values depending on the arguments of the patched method call.

```
from mock import patch

import unittest

class MyClass(object):
    def one_func(self, query):
        return ''

    def foo(self):
        test = self.one_func("SELECT * from Users;")
        test1 = self.one_func("SELECT * from Addresses;")
        return test, test1

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(MyClass, 'one_func')
    def test_foo(self, one_func_mock):
        # side_effect can be a list of responses that will be returned in
        # subsequent calls
        one_func_mock.side_effect = ['users', 'addresses']
        self.assertEqual(('users', 'addresses'), MyClass().foo())

        # side_effect can also be a method which will return different mock
        # responses depending on args:
        def side_effect(args):
            if args == "SELECT * from Users;":
                return 'other users'

            if args == "SELECT * from Addresses;":
                return 'other addresses'
        
        one_func_mock.side_effect = side_effect
        self.assertEqual(('other users', 'other addresses'), MyClass().foo())

unittest.main()
```